# Django: Before or after __init__?

Tags: django

I am a bit confused with `super()`. Should `self.order = order` come before or after it? It seems to work both when I tested it. I just use it so often, so I think it's good I understand it better.

```
def __init__(self, order, *args, **kwargs):
    self.order = order  # BEFORE OR AFTER __init__?
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we want any defined behaviors of child classes to override those of the parent classes, so you should usually call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` first, before possibly overriding selective instance variables of the parent class with the child's own versions.

In some cases, however, you want a different behavior of the parent class's `__init__()` in the child class, and you can do so by modifying `args` and/or `kwargs` first before calling the parent class's `__init__()`.

So it really all depends on how you want your child class to customize the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the class, but for the most part it doesn't matter.

I tend to `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` first unless there's a reason not to do so (for instance modifying `kwargs` before it is passed up).